# Sympy, juputer notebook. Decimals rather than fractions

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, sympy

I have an issue with regard to sympy and jupyter notebooks.

Whenever i display any fraction it automatically formats the fraction into a decimal

an image of an example is attached to the post

[image: example of issue]

is there a way to make sympy display the fraction instead of the decimal?

**EDIT:**
On MacOs, and possibly also linux, jupyter has a tendency to reformat the values to decimals, when used in formulas. To circumvent this, you can define any fractal with S(x)/y and it will be formatted corectly.

Comment: See [sympy gotchas](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/explanation/gotchas.html#python-numbers-vs-sympy-numbers): you should be very careful with the division (`/`), as Python converts the expression to unexact floats before Sympy gets a chance to create an exact symbolic expression.

Comment: If you use Jupyter Lab, it will automatically display them as fractions.

Comment: Look at `1/4` by itself.  Aren't you  just doing `display(0.25)`?